# How to make a label change to a text box using jQuery

Tags: jquery, textbox, label

I have some labels that I want to allow users to edit. Is it possible to do this and if so how (using jQuery).

When a user clicks a label, it turns into a textbox, which has the existing "label text" contained within. When the user then edits the label and clicks somewhere other than the text box, the value is saved.

This might actually be a few pieces of functionality in one, if you could help, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are describing is often referred to as an "in place editor".  You should check out the [Jeditable plugin demo page](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html).  I think it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This isn't your fault I'm sure, but people clicking on that link be warned - that link has some very strange political stuff on it that is hard to miss. That is the weirdest demo page I have ever seen.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into some of the ["edit in place"](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugins.

Check out the [live demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html).